# Nuclear Compton Scattering Data

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, data

Is there a repository where one can find unpolarized nuclear Compton scattering data $\gamma (Z,N)\rightarrow \gamma (Z,N)$ for specific nuclei $(Z,N)$?  or even some parametrization of structure functions that loosely follows the data?

Comment: I don't know of any, but check out http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Physics/Particle/Software/, as well as the PSI website. They mention a free service (you don't run it on your machine) that simulates scattering events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exploring the [National Nuclear Data Center](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/). If I search the [Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) for "incident particle: g" and "outgoing particle: g" I get datasets for most, but not all, nuclei. There are other databases hosted by the NNDC as well, and all are well-referenced to the experimental literature.

Comment: Of course, the ENSDFs are a bear to read and interpret. But then most major simulation packages already know how to do that.